# How do I open custom ports in my iptables firewall?

Tags: iptables, centos6

I need IPTables, like everyone else, but I don't use it enough to really keep my knowledge complete and fresh.

The setup utility in CentOS is too basic. It doesn't seem to allow me to open up custom ports, just standard ones.

I need a text-based way to open up custom ports in my firewall. What should I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`system-config-firewall-tui` is the "stock" text-based firewall configuration tool for RHEL/CentOS. It is perfectly capable of opening custom ports.

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> until you reach **Customize** on the first screen.
[image]

Then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> until you reach **Forward** to skip the list of standard ports.
[image]

Then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> until you reach **Add**, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
[image]

Then enter the port (e.g. `5900`) and protocol (e.g. `tcp`) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
[image]

When done adding ports, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> until you reach **Close**.
[image]

Finally, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> until you reach **OK**. Your firewall is now saved.
[image]

Comment: Ohhhhhh, must use the "forward" option..... I thought that was like the "forward" section of the iptables output.... I see it now!

Comment: In this case "Forward" means "Next". They really should change that...