# Can't get to Dell OMSA webpage on my server

Tags: centos, dell, centos6, dell-openmanage

I'm running CentOS 6.3 x64 on a Dell PowerEdge R520. I have run the following two commands as per [This Wiki](http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Repository/OMSA)

```
sudo wget -q -O - http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/latest/bootstrap.cgi | bash  
sudo yum install srvadmin-all
```

All the related services appear to be running. But, when I try to access

```
http://myserver:1311
```

the page doesn't resolve.
When I try to access the webpage from the physical server, I am presented with a page that has 4 boxes and a question mark.

Any Help Is Much Appreciated.

EDIT: Apparently I suck a QA-ing.
The problem was what when I tried to access the OMSA webpage for my server from another machine, the page would be "unable to load". But, if I open a web browser while I'm at the server that I have OMSA installed on, then I am presented with a page containing four boxes and a question mark. Turns out that I just didn't have the appropriate ports open. My apologies to you all for not being clear and thank you all for your help.

Comment: You might want to spell out exactly what "doesnt resolve" mean. Do you mean the hostname or is there a 404 or connection refused? You might also want to explain what "physical server" means. Is there some virtualisation invoved, do you mean different server or what?

Comment: Fixed the description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to [open port 1311 in your firewall](https://serverfault.com/a/447715/126632). (You may also want to restrict it to specific IP address ranges or other criteria, but this should get you going.)

Comment: That did it! I had to explicitly allow port 1311 and http and https. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

That link is an https link by default. Have you tried using `https://` instead of `http://`? Also, do you have an iptables rule that would block an inbound connection on port 1311?

Comment: Accessing the page at https:// also does not yield anything. I do not have an iptables block for port 1311.

Comment: My only reject line reads:  
REJECT    all  --  0.0.0.0/0        0.0.0.0/0        reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Comment: That is going to drop all traffic...

Answer (score 0):

If you just installed omsa, be sure the [service is started](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN156111/EN)

On my CentOS 6 box, the script to call is:

`/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin/srvadmin-services.sh start`