# Centos firewall blocking incoming connections

Tags: centos, iptables

After installing Centos 5.8 I could not pick up any open ports using nmap. So I ran the command #iptables --flush and all started working. However, after about 2 days I could not connect again and had to run the command.

1)How can I permanently ensure that my ports are open

2)What could be causing them to be shut in the first place since I did not touch the iptables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Configure** the firewall to open only the ports that you need to have open.](https://serverfault.com/a/447715/126632) Disabling the firewall entirely is very dangerous. You can use the `system-config-firewall-tui` command to configure it from a terminal.

Comment: This is definitely a smart answer. Never disable the firewall if you value the internet at large. Even if you have no assets on your machine you will still open the door for attackers to use your box in a botnet or as a spam agent.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're running into the default firewall. Try these:

```
service iptables stop
chkconfig iptables off
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to disable iptables:

```
service iptables save
service iptables stop
chkconfig iptables off
```

and for IPv6

```
service ip6tables save
service ip6tables stop
chkconfig ip6tables off
```