# Linux noob here. RHEL v6.7. Iptables default configuration. Not secure, right?

Tags: linux, iptables

Thanks for having me!

So... I did a fresh install of RHEL v6.7. I was setting up just NTP service and followed some tutorial on the interwebs. At some point is this tutorial it suggested that I should open port udp 123 so the server could receive NTP querys from other clients.

After that fresh install no configuration was done whatsoever.

When I checked the iptables service this is what I got.

```
[root@SVNTPRJO01 ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I'm not a linux guy but reading man pages and some blog posts I understand that because of rule number 3 on the INPUT chain this server would accept anything from anywhere, including udp 123, right?

Is my understanding correct?

This server only has one nic (eth0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The firewall is fine.

You need to add `-v` to see the full output.

Then you will see that the rule you think is allowing access from anywhere, actually allows access only on the `lo` interface, that is, anywhere on localhost.

You can [open ports in the firewall configuration](https://serverfault.com/a/447715/126632)  by running the `system-config-firewall-tui` command in a terminal, or `system-config-firewall` on a graphical system.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I feel so dumb. Sorry for this stupid question.

Comment: It's not so dumb. I hate this about iptables, that it doesn't show you the complete rules unless you use `-v`. It's not something I expect the average person to know.

Comment: That tiny detail explained a lot to me. This same tutorial I used also suggested that I should open an OUTPUT rule so this NTP server could connect to a higher stratum NTP server. But since the default policy for OUTPUT chain is ACCEPT I understand that that rule is not necessary, right? (sorry to bother you...)

Comment: No, you don't need explicit OUTPUT rules, unless you set up egress filtering (which is a whole other question).